# Workflow Services Duplex Binding

Tags: .net, binding, workflow, service, duplex

Is Duplex Binding supported in windows Workflow Services and WCF integration?  Can an activity "register" with a WCF service and then can a WCF service raise an event to the registered activity in the workflow when it needs to?

Answer (score 1):

I just came across this and though it would help you out.

[workflow-4-services-and-duplex-communications.aspx](http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2010/05/03/workflow-4-services-and-duplex-communications.aspx)

Comment: Please let me know if my answer was helpful by making this the selected answer or comment if it was not.